# CodeIgniter returns 404 for all routes but works

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have strange problem with CodeIgniter and routing system and can't find solution for it, so: I have several routes such as

```
'forum/(:num)'
    => 'forum/category/$1',
'forum/(:num)/(page:any)'
    => 'forum/category/$1/$2',
```

and them works, but return 404 code in header.

I mean I don't get 404 page, correct HTML returns and page's content displays correctly for my forum's categories. But I'm getting 404 in header (Network tab in Firebug), so I can't work with POST data correctly.

If I request /forum/ - 200 Ok returns, but when I trying to get routed page, I get right page, but with 404 Not Found.

I'm using PHP5.4+Apache2 on Linux host, if it will help You to give me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution! Maybe it will save someone's time.

Problem wasn't in CodeIgniter, I've found solution in activation mod_rewrite. Yes, that worked, but wan't activated in Apache.

Just try to do

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and restart apache service after

```
sudo service apache restart
```

And all routed pages will return 200 Ok

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the solution. This was driving me crazy after a new server upgrade!

Comment: @Winterain glad it helped not only me! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked, but I did this instead:

At the end of my controller I put this:

```
$this->output->set_status_header('200');
```

and actually though that worked, the problem turned out to be a controller name that conflicted with a real directory name...