# How create a container based on php image with a2enmod rewrite enabled?

Tags: php, docker, docker-container

I noticed that the default php image `php:5.6-apache` comes with mod rewrite turned off. (I got a problem that was solved here: [CodeIgniter returns 404 for all routes but works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806531/codeigniter-returns-404-for-all-routes-but-works) by enabling it).

I need to run `a2enmod rewrite` everytime inside the container in order to work properly.

How can I configure my php container to be initiated with this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest maintain your own image based on php:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Then, use your image to start container.